# Why is there an error with my sort function (PYTHON)?

Tags: python, sorting

I am a beginner at python programming and I've been trying to tackle writing a sort function that would sort out the numbers of a given list from least to greatest (I ALREADY KNOW ABOUT THE "sort." FUNCTION). I wrote one out and I keep getting: *"IndexError: list index out of range"*

```
a = [5,3,1,2,4]

s = 0
n = [len(a)-1]
sn = a[0]
i = 0
b = []

for item in a:
    while i < n:
        if sn > a[i+1]:
            sn = a[i+1]
    i = i + 1
    b.append(sn)
    a.remove(sn)
    n = n-1
    i = 0
    sn = a[0]

print(b)
```

The way I'm going about it is by comparing the first (0th) term of the list to the rest and determining whether it is the least number, and then adding it to a new list (b) and just redefining the first list (a) as the new one (b). Can any of you help me out?

Comment: You're setting n equal to the index of nothing... That's the problem most likely. Also, meaningful variable names are really helpful.

Comment: do you know the `a.sort()` function ?

Comment: yes i do know it, im just doing this for self practice

Comment: Change n = len(a)-1 instead of n = [len(a)-1]

Comment: Is your indentation correct? The line `sn = a[i+1]` line certainly needs to be indented under the `if` (or you'll get a syntax error), but I'm wondering about the rest. As the code stands right now, you only ever move one value from `a` to `b`.

Comment: I made some indentation errors when I wrote the question out, but i fixed them. The last 5 lines before the "print(b)" should have been in the for-loop

Comment: If you're still getting an `IndexError` with the current code, can you please edit in the full traceback? I can't imagine that error coming up, and perhaps the traceback will show a bit more of what is going on.

Comment: I'm not sure what a traceback is or how to perform one...if it helps, the error comes up on the line: `if sn > a[i+1]:`

Answer (score 0):

Try indenting i=i+1 because otherwise there is an infinite loop and changing for item in a: to for item in range(len(a)): because as you remove items from a, a gets smaller, so  it will not run on the whole list. You also need to move sn=a[0] to before the item is removed from a because otherwise the list will be empty on the last iteration when you try to take the first item of the list.

EDIT:

```
while i < n:
        if sn > a[i+1]:
            sn = a[i+1]
        i = i + 1
```

could be replaced with

```
sn=max(a)
```